# Referencing to objects in other scripts [Unity]

Tags: unity

Hello guys just a quick question, I'm learning from this book and I got this error where

```
var backgroundBounds = GameObject.Find("background")
 .renderer.bounds;
```

is deprecated way of doing thins instead it says do it like this:

```
public SpriteRenderer backgroundSprite;
backgroundSprite = (SpriteRenderer)GetComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer));
```

But when I set my GameObject to it which contains SpriteRenderer, on hitting the play button it will disappear and throw null exception.

Comment: @SeanCarey the first one is the example in the book, the second one me trying to experiment with it so it will work, I just make a global variable and then set to it in the engine.

Comment: Here, I posted an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var backgroundBounds = GameObject.Find("background").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds;
```